# Fugitive commands unavailable after opening .vimrc to edit

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-fugitive

My system is an OS X 10.6 with MacVim 7.3 (GUI) and Vim 7.2 (on iTerm).

On MacVim, Fugitive does not work at all.

On Vim, it is a little bit different. I have set a mapping to open the `.vimrc` file as follows:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>ev :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

Just after opening vim, all Fugitive commands are available, but after opening the `.vimrc` file using the mapping above I can't issue any of the Fugitive `:G*` commands. If I open the `.vimrc` file normally (i.e. with `:e ~/.vimrc`) everything is fine.

My entire `.vim` dir (with `.vimrc` as `vimrc` in the root) can be accessed [here](https://github.com/freitass/vimfiles).

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "On MacVim, Fugitive does not work at all."? What are the symptoms? For the other part, try replacing `$MYVIMRC` in your mapping by `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc` and also try doing manually `:e $MYVIMRC`. I suspect the issue has something to do with  your `~/.vimrc` being a symlink to `~/.vim/vimrc`.

Comment: @romainl: Sorry, by "On MacVim, Fugitive does not work at all." I meant that the Fugitive commands are not available from start. I don't even need to issue `\ev` as I do for "terminal vim". What is awkward is that I have  seven other plugins installed and they work just fine, only Fugitive is behaving that way. I'll investigate the symlink. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fugitive's functions are only available if the file in question is part of a Git repository. It's likely that your `.vimrc` file isn't under Git version control, or if it is, that you've edited it via a symlinked path, which Fugitive does not handle at the time of writing.

If your `.vimrc` file really is under version control, you can fix this by calling `:edit` on the *canonical* path to the file, rather than via any symbolic links, which will prompt Fugitive to correctly find the `.git` subdirectory and the metadata within.

Comment: Indeed! I thought that Fugitive was based on `:pwd` but it's based on the current file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your `$MYVIMRC` is a symlink, try this mapping instead.

```
noremap <leader>ev :execute 'e ' . resolve(expand($MYVIMRC))<CR>
```

It will open the target `vimrc` file, which is in a git repo and thus can be picked up by Fugitive.